# How to perform gap analysis to determine missing numbers in column of consecutive numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to perform a gap analysis in one Excel column that has consecutive numbers and have all missing values copied to a new column.

A gap in a number analysis is a missing value in the number sequence.
Lets say I want to perform a gap analysis on 1,3,4,5,9. The gaps are 2,6,7,8.

The code runs but if I select a column range that has no missing values I get a runtime error.

How can I fix the code so if there are no missing values a message box can say so.

```vb
Sub missing()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim d As Object, a, c()
    Dim i As Long, mx As Long, mn As Long
    
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a range:", _
      Title:="Extract missing values", _
      Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    a = rng
    mx = Application.Max(a): mn = Application.Min(a)
    ReDim c(1 To mx - mn + 1, 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(a): d(a(i, 1)) = 1: Next i
    
    For i = mn To mx
        If d(i) <> 1 Then k = k + 1: c(k, 1) = i
    Next i
    
    Range("B1") = "Missing Values"
    Range("B2").Resize(k) = c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what a *gap* is?

Comment: Hi basically a gap in a number analysis is a missing value in the number sequence. Lets say i want to perform a gap analysis on 1,3,4,5,9. The gaps are as follows 2,6,7,8

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know that.

Comment: Welcome VBasic2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, replace:

```
Range("B2").Resize(k) = c
```

with:

```
If k > 0 Then
    Range("H2").Resize(k) = c
Else
    MsgBox "No gaps in the selected range..."
End If
```

I think, you should mention that your code should process a range having consecutive numbers and it makes the gap analysis to extract the missing ones. I have to deduce this aspect only reading the code...

Comment: Oh it was that simple! I feel silly. Thanks this solved my issue. I will mark it as the answer

Comment: @Yanick: Glad I could help! But you must be more atentive when place a question. We do not have to spend time for understanding what your code wants to accomplish. This is something you must accurately explain. Doing it more appropriately, me or somebody else could answer it faster...:)

Comment: FaneDuru apologies if the description above was not clear but thanks again. I will edit the above description for future viewers to understand better

Answer (score 0):

### Gap Analysis

- Since I learned what a gap in this case is, I thought I'll utilize this knowledge by playing around with your procedure and making a few changes (hopefully improvements).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub missingValues()
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Select a range:", _
        Title:="Extract missing values", _
        Default:=Selection.Address, _
        Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You canceled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rng = rng.Columns(1)
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Only one cell selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Calulate Min and Max.
    Dim mn As Long: mn = Application.Min(Data)
    Dim mx As Long: mx = Application.Max(Data)
    If mx = mn Then
        MsgBox "No number sequence: Min = Max."
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Write (and count) unique values from Data Array to Unique Dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        dict(Data(i, 1)) = dict(Data(i, 1)) + 1
    Next i
    
    ' Write missing values to (oversized) Gap Array.
    Dim Gap() As Long: ReDim Gap(1 To mx - mn + 1, 1 To 1)
    Dim k As Long
    For i = mn To mx
        Select Case dict(i)
            Case 0 ' OK: No occurrences.
                k = k + 1
                Gap(k, 1) = i
            Case 1 ' OK: one occurrence.
            Case Else ' Multiple occurrences.
                MsgBox "Multiple occurrences of a number detected."
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    Next i
    
    ' Write missing values from Gap Array to Destination Range.
    With Range("B1")
        '.Worksheet.Columns(.Column).ClearContents
        .Value = "Missing Values"
        If k > 0 Then
            .Offset(1).Resize(k).Value = Gap
            MsgBox "Found " & k & " gaps in range '" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "'."
        Else
            MsgBox "No gaps found in range '" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "'."
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help and enthusiasm, i will surely give this a go now!